# Oracle-XE ошибка при импорте: IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown

Tags: oracle

Добрый день

У меня 2 виртуальных сервера, нужно перенести БД с 1 на 2.

Сделал bkp файл.

Перенес на сервер, выполняю: 
imp user/password file=file.bkp full=yes

Получаю ошибку:

```
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sun Nov 22 07:45:10 2015
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

Версия сервера: Oracle-xe-10.2.0

```
select * from nls_database_parameters; 

**NLS_LANGUAGE**
AMERICAN
**NLS_TERRITORY**
AMERICA
**NLS_CURRENCY**
$
**NLS_ISO_CURRENCY**
AMERICA
**NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS**
.,
**NLS_CHARACTERSET**
AL32UTF8
**NLS_CALENDAR**
GREGORIAN
**NLS_DATE_FORMAT**
DD-MON-RR
**NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**
AMERICAN
**NLS_SORT**
BINARY
**NLS_TIME_FORMAT**
HH.MI.SSXFF AM
**NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT**
DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
**NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT**
HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
**NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT**
DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
**NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY**
$
**NLS_COMP**
BINARY
**NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS**
BYTE
**NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP**
FALSE
**NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET**
AL16UTF16
**NLS_RDBMS_VERSION**
11.2.0.2.0
```

Кодировка на исходном сервере:

```
1   NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
2   NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
3   NLS_CURRENCY    $
4   NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
5   NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
6   NLS_CHARACTERSET    CL8MSWIN1251
7   NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
8   NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
9   NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
10  NLS_SORT    BINARY
11  NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
12  NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
13  NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
14  NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
15  NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
16  NLS_COMP    BINARY
17  NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
18  NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
19  NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
20  NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал dmp файл, он импортировался корректно.

Answer (score 2):

Эта ошибка означает, что у вас битый дамп, или же, если вы бэкап делали не с помощью `exp`.

Если первое, то только заново делать бэкап.

Если вы делали бэкап `expdp`, используйте `impdp`.

Если не помогло, почитайте [это](https://community.oracle.com/message/734478) и [это](https://community.oracle.com/thread/870104?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Делал, используя exp. Как понять, битый файл - или нет? Ошибок при экспорте не было. Ссылки, которые Вы дали, я читал перед тем, как создать вопрос.

Comment: Попробую выполнить повторный exp, но не думаю, что это поможет.

Comment: @VyacheslavGroshenkov а копируете вы чем дамп?

Comment: Боюсь все гораздо хуже. Oracle XE не умеет работать с кодировками (это его ограничение) и может принять дамп только из БД с точно такой же кодировкой. Какие у вас кодировки на экспортирующем сервере ? Еще может быть из за сильно разных версий

Comment: Mike. Добавил в исходный пост кодировку с сервера, откуда делаю импорт - есть различая, некоторые, Suvitruf - копирую через WinSCP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283164/import-export-oracle-scheme-with-correct-character-set  Т.е. рекомендуется при запуска exp и imp насильно в переменных окружения поставить одинаковые кодировки. И очень рекомендую выбрать кодировку вашей XE

Comment: Сделал export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8, а так же сделал экспорт в dmp, а не bkp. Буду пробовать.. спасибо!